# Analysis model vs. executable implementation of model?

Tags: modeling, simulation, model

I asked this question on the [Operations Research Beta](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/4728/analysis-model-vs-executable-implementation-of-model) site, but haven't gotten an answer after 5 days.  Hoping that this Stack Exchange site is more suitable than Stack Overflow (though the latter does deal with implementation, which participants might readily discern from modelling).

In my post-graduate research and subsequent career in operational analysis, the difference between following seems to have become clearer with the years: (1) a model of a problem or operations in the real world and (2) implementation of a corresponding analysis tool that applies the model to actual data.

Item (1) can take many forms: A collection of inter-related equations, a schematic, and/or a word description.  But one cannot take item (1) and apply it to actual data to get the results.

To apply a model to actual data, the model must be realized via item (2), which can take the form of spreadsheets, coding (preferably in a 4th generation language), software whose execution is specified via a graphical schematic language [1], digital circuit/systems modelling environments [2], discrete event simulators, optimization packages, etc.

**Is there an actual paper, book, or some preferably non-contentious source that describes this distinction?**  Some of what I've found seem not to distinguish between the two items, preferring instead to distinguish their amalgamation  from "implementation" of recommendations falling out of the analysis. The latter is not what I mean by "implementation" in the context of this question.

**ANNEX: My personal view of modelling layers**

As suggested in the comments, I'll refer to a concrete example.  It
is not in the area that I work in, but rather, from what I recall in
a course.

Before any modelling, someone may have a problem.  He/she can
describe the problem, but at this point, I don't consider it a model.
For example, a wholesale distribution centre might want to get more
profit from its operations, but isn't sure where or how to sharpen things up.

The salient parameters and relationships of a real world problem need
to be identified.  This representation of the problem is an
abstraction, so it is a model, but it is still in the language of the
problem domain.  In the above example, say the manager's new hire happened
to have taken a operations research course before.  He/she recognizes
that the operations resemble a linear programming model from class.
The parameters were the cost of shipping product different retailers,
the demand from the various retailers, etc., and the decision variables
represent how much to send to each retailer.  The model doesn't represent
all aspects of the problem, but using it may improve efficiency over
just winging the decisions.

Normally, an algorithmic model then needs to be identified, e.g., evolutionary algorithms, LP/ILP/BLP, etc. In the above, the new hire chooses LP, since it was an LP model that he recognized as roughly representing actual operations.  Strictly speaking, however, one could choose (say) genetic algorithms (GAs), simulated annealing (SA), exhaustive search, etc.  Normally, a mapping is also needed from the model in the problem domain to the algorithmic model. The LP variables can be found in any textbook, and it is simply a matter of stating what real-world variables correspond to the textbook LP variables.  Different search algorithms might provide more flexibility in what the variables can represent, and the relationships that can be specified between variables.  Again, since the new hire recognized the similarity between the operations and an academic LP problem, the mapping of variables is straightforward.

This mapping is what I mean by **analysis model** because it is how one plans to analyze the problem.  It encompasses both the abstraction of the problem, the selection of the optimization method, and the mapping of variables from the former to the latter.  In so doing, one chooses what aspects of the real world will be represented and what aspects will be ignored.

The executable code then needs to be planned at the design/architectural level, e.g., the object oriented classes to manage the data and bookkeeping.  Then someone needs to write the code and test it. Many people in my circles refers to this *activity* as implementation, but the *noun* "implementation* also refers to the resulting code (or executable schematic). The implementation still represents the problem, so is technically a model, albeit an "executable" one that can be applied to input data to generate a result. It's design and development, however, is quite different from the previous 2 models, so I try to maintain this distinction by referring to it as [an **executable**] **implementation**, leaving out the word "model".

**NOTES**

**[1]** Core Sim, G2 ReThink, LabView, etc. 
**[2]** These may use a combination of schematics and text languages for specifying system behaviour.

Comment: As I understand it, you're interested in the subject that describes some part of the overall process that's given in the annex.  Specifically, which part of the process described in the concrete example are you interested in?

Comment: I'm actually interested in a (possibly online) source that draws the distinction between the analysis model above versus the executable implementation, and explains this difference. I and some colleagues took it for granted that everyone would recognize this distinction, but I couldn't actually corroborate this from an online search.

Comment: The analysis modelling is book, brain, and paper work while implementation involves planning the organization of code, crafting it, and/or schematic capture.  The former may be theoretically challenging, while the latter may require experience leveraging commercial applications, design patterns, and technologies/standards for interfacing enterprise applications. It is a realization of the analysis scheme that can be applied to data.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about what's simply called [**_modeling_**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modeling_and_simulation)?  Or, the even more abstract aspect of it'd be called [**_binding_**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding_problem).

Comment: I'm still fuzzy on exactly what you're trying to point to, in specific, so it's hard to recommend further reading because these are huge topics with tons of available literature.  The overall binding/modeling/implementation/solving pattern is common throughout many fields, including most of the sciences, engineerings, medicine, business, constructed maths/logics, etc.; probably lots of reading out there you may enjoy.

Comment: To help explain a bit: when you first have some notion of _something_, before sense is made of it, it needs to be bound (binded).  Binding's a fairly abstract process that involves creating conceptual anchors for a topic, such that it might be addressed and considered through more formal; before something's bound, you don't really have a solid conceptual grasp of it.  Once various bound concepts are available, models can be constructed.  Then we can construct implementations of models, and then execute those implementations.

Comment: I think your cited concepts of modelling an binding do correspond to elements of my layers of models, but not one-to-one.  The Wikipedia modelling & simulation page (M&S) is about modelling specific for simulation, but a system of equations can still model real world processes.  It gets solved numerically, but not actually simulated.

Comment: Your reference to modelling corresponds to my layers of modelling. LP equations do model a problem, but they're 1 layer. Each variable corresponds to a real world metric; this is your "binding" (I call it mapping). However, the collection of such real-world metrics, and the relationships between them, as implied by the LP equations, is just another model. They only capture some of the actual problem. There are factors not represented by the LP variables. We hope that they are small effects and that the implied relationships represented by the linear LP expressions are somewhat accurate.

Comment: At this point, we have a common understanding of the division between modelling and implementation. On each half of that dividing line, much can be read about, but I was wondering if there was a source that speaks specifically to this division.  The skills needed on either side seem to be very different.

Comment: I suspect that most books on the general topic of how-to-write-computer-models, aimed toward scientists and engineers, would tend to talk about that.  For example, if you ask a physicist, they might tell you to figure out what relevant phenomena are involved in your domain, then write up some corresponding equations, then solve as much as you can analytically, then tackle the rest through a variety of numerical techniques.

Comment: Yes, and operational analysts/researchers as well. That's why those I know took this distinction for granted. I was hoping that this "universally" recognized boundary line had common terminology, as it would be helpful to point to it for those unfamiliar with it. But it also may not be feasible to have them read a treatise on modelling without a succinct focus on this particular division. A readily available and short online source that has an authoritative or credible reputation would be even more helpful. I haven't found such a succinct focus in my online wanderings, which surprised me.

Comment: Part of the problem is that this division applies not just to modelling done by engineers and scientists, but also business analysts and policy shops. The division still exists, but the terms are treated in all sorts of different ways. The online source's explanation needs to be recognizably applicable across the board. Even within physical modelling and operations research, however, implementation seems to often refer to the decision recommended by the analysis rather than an executable realization of the model that is used for analysis.

Answer (score 2):

## Effective procedure.

An [***effective procedure***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_method) is an executable specification of an abstract model.

Effective procedures can take the form of actual software you run on your computer, or they can be abstract software you run on an [abstract computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_machine).  Either way, they're more imperative in nature, specifying a procedure that can be performed, rather than merely a constraint-based description of a model.

You might also be interested in:

- [constructive mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(mathematics)) (as opposed to [classical mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_mathematics));
- [computability theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability_theory).

Comment: Your answer gives a glimpse of the fact that there are layers of modelling, from the problem as described in the real world to something that actually runs on a computer. I've now elaborated on at least one possible layering of models in my question. Your term "effective procedure" seems to straddle: (1) my "algorithmic model" and (2) pseudocoding in planning the design of my "exectuable implementation".

Comment: As such, it doesn't quite draw the distinction that I'm looking for. I'm beginning to wonder whether my distinction is particular to operational analysts who map real world problems to known algorithmic models rather than mathmeticians who push the boundaries of those algorithmic models. It would be helpful to find an articulation of this particular distinction between analysis model an executable implementation.

Comment: @user2153235: You're asking about pretty simple stuff, so there's probably a common term for what you're trying to refer to.  It's just hard to tell what you're trying to say because some of the basic terminology seems missing.

Comment: @user2153235: Since the terminology seems a tad sketchy, I'd recommend keeping it simple.  Perhaps describe a hypothetical scenario where Alice starts from a basic problem and finds a solution, going through all of the steps?  Then once that basic example's laid out, you could ask what a specific section of it's called.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I added some detail to the Annex of the question to illustrate the stages of the problem modelling.